# Is there an workaround to handle error “Error: 4 DEADLINE_EXCEEDED: Deadline exceeded” in Cloud Functions

Tags: node.js, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, google-cloud-functions

I am writing to Firestore using batch writes of Cloud Functions. 
At that time, **Error: 4 DEADLINE_EXCEEDED: Deadline exceeded** is displayed and writing is interrupted.

After looking at this question,[Error: 4 DEADLINE_EXCEEDED: Deadline Exceeded at Object.exports.createStatusError - GCP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55067252/error-4-deadline-exceeded-deadline-exceeded-at-object-exports-createstatuserro) I knew that the content of the error reached the quota for writing, but I don't know how to deal with the quota.  If you know how to solve it, please let me know.

Here is my code.

```
exports.batchTest = functions.region('asia-northeast1').pubsub.schedule('every 60 minutes').onRun(async (snapshot, context) => {


    let db = admin.firestore();
    // Get a new write batch
    let batch = db.batch();

    const userRef = db.collection('user');
    const userQs = await userRef.get();

    userQs.forEach(userDocs => {
        let userId = userDocs.id;
        let likeRef = db.collection('like').doc(userId).collection('like').get().then(docs => {

            if (docs.exists) {
                const subLikeRef = db.collection('like').doc(userId).collection('like').doc(docs.id);
                batch.delete(subLikeRef)
                    .then(function () {
                        console.log("success");
                        return true;
                    })
                    .catch(function (error) {
                        console.error("Error", error);
                        return true;
                    });

            }
            return null;
        });


    });




    // Commit the batch
    return batch.commit().then(function () {
        // ...
        return null;
    });


}
);
```

Comment: This question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61822332/deadline-exceeded-while-adding-tasks-to-google-cloud-tasks helped me - make sure to await on your async calls

Answer (score 1):

this error is related to the requests that you're making are taking too long.

In order to avoid this, you can either modify your logic to write a smaller batch of data each time your function is triggered or you can try to increase the timeout value.

You can take a look at [this firebase documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/manage-functions#set_timeout_and_memory_allocation[) and [this document](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/functions/function_builder_.functionbuilder.html#run-with) to increase the timeout value.

Comment: I am getting this issue and I am not using firebase functions. I am using AWS Lambda with AWS SQS. I added the queue to handle retries when this error occurs. I am unable to reproduce this problem though.

I wrote 10,000 records into the database into different collections / documents milliseconds apart and did not find the issue. the document being written is a few lines of text at best.

Comment: 2nd link goes to a 404 not found page. Pretty typical of firebase documentation these days...