# DEADLINE_EXCEEDED while adding tasks to Google Cloud Tasks

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-tasks

I'm occasionally getting an error called `DEADLINE_EXCEEDED` while adding tasks to Google Cloud Tasks from Node.js client. It's only 17 tasks that I tried to add in a for-loop. Not sure why this is happening occasionally and sometimes works perfectly fine!

Here is the detailed error log:

```js
Error: 4 DEADLINE_EXCEEDED: Deadline exceeded
    at Object.callErrorFromStatus (/Users/gijo/Desktop/workspace/flying-press-server/node_modules/@grpc/grpc-js/build/src/call.js:30:26)
    at Object.onReceiveStatus (/Users/gijo/Desktop/workspace/flying-press-server/node_modules/@grpc/grpc-js/build/src/client.js:175:52)
    at Object.onReceiveStatus (/Users/gijo/Desktop/workspace/flying-press-server/node_modules/@grpc/grpc-js/build/src/client-interceptors.js:341:141)
    at Object.onReceiveStatus (/Users/gijo/Desktop/workspace/flying-press-server/node_modules/@grpc/grpc-js/build/src/client-interceptors.js:304:181)
    at Http2CallStream.outputStatus (/Users/gijo/Desktop/workspace/flying-press-server/node_modules/@grpc/grpc-js/build/src/call-stream.js:115:74)
    at Http2CallStream.maybeOutputStatus (/Users/gijo/Desktop/workspace/flying-press-server/node_modules/@grpc/grpc-js/build/src/call-stream.js:154:22)
    at Http2CallStream.endCall (/Users/gijo/Desktop/workspace/flying-press-server/node_modules/@grpc/grpc-js/build/src/call-stream.js:140:18)
    at Http2CallStream.cancelWithStatus (/Users/gijo/Desktop/workspace/flying-press-server/node_modules/@grpc/grpc-js/build/src/call-stream.js:443:14)
    at Timeout.<anonymous> (/Users/gijo/Desktop/workspace/flying-press-server/node_modules/@grpc/grpc-js/build/src/deadline-filter.js:59:28)
    at listOnTimeout (internal/timers.js:549:17) {
  code: 4,
  details: 'Deadline exceeded',
  metadata: Metadata { internalRepr: Map {}, options: {} }
}
```

I thought I hit some quotas. But on checking, none of them has exceeded.

[image]

Here is how I've created the queue (upsert):

```js
const client = require('./client');

module.exports = async (queue_name, concurrent) => {
  return client.updateQueue({
    queue: {
      name: client.queuePath(
        process.env.GCP_PROJECT,
        process.env.GCP_QUEUE_LOCATION,
        queue_name,
      ),
      rateLimits: {
        maxConcurrentDispatches: concurrent,
        maxDispatchesPerSecond: concurrent,
        maxBurstSize: 100,
      },
      retryConfig: {
        maxAttempts: 3,
        unlimitedAttempts: false,
        maxRetryDuration: {
          seconds: 3600,
        },
        minBackoff: {
          seconds: 60,
        },
        maxBackoff: {
          seconds: 300,
        },
        maxDoublings: 3,
      },
    },
  });
};
```

and here is how I'm adding tasks:

```js
const client = require('./client');

module.exports = async (queue_name, url, config) => {
  return client.createTask({
    parent: client.queuePath(
      process.env.GCP_PROJECT,
      process.env.GCP_QUEUE_LOCATION,
      queue_name,
    ),
    task: {
      httpRequest: {
        httpMethod: 'POST',
        headers: {
          'Content-Type': 'application/json',
        },
        url: `${process.env.OPTIMIZER_URL}/optimize-page`,
        body: Buffer.from(JSON.stringify({ url, config })).toString(
          'base64',
        ),
      },
    },
  });
};
```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I've hit this exact issue before in Cloud Functions and App Engine when creating tasks. It happened because I wasn't properly `await`ing on the create task promise. This causes the request to hang open and eventually hit a timeout, but it only happens sporadically. Basically, the request ends before the async call is completed, which causes issues in "serverless" runtimes like App Engine, Cloud Functions, Cloud Run, etc.

To fix this, ensure you are doing an `await` on the call to `createTask` or otherwise `await` on all of the task promises before returning from the request, e.g. with `Promise.all()`.

Comment: Yes, I was not awaiting it. I've now converted it to `Promise.all()`. I'll test it again in detail and revert back. Thanks a lot

Comment: Yes, looks like it was the issue!

Comment: No promise.all doesn't resolve the issue it just add an abstraction and you may end up not creating all your tasks. I was using promise.all and realised that when trying to create over 5K tasks, I was not getting the count of tasks created. GCP does not handle well conccurent tasks creation, bug still open GCP. I create my tasks synchronously to avoid issue, even if it takes more time

Comment: This did the trick for me too, thanks! It was actually higher up the chain - even though I was `await`ing the call to `createTask`, I was not `await`ing the call to the containing function.

Answer (score 1):

I was having the same issue with a Cloud Run creating Cloud Task and this sort the issue out for me.

```
const call_options = {
  timeout: 300, // millis
};

const request = { parent, task };
const [response] = await client.createTask(request, call_options);
```

There is a long discussion around this issue in [here](https://github.com/googleapis/nodejs-tasks/issues/397#issuecomment-846231040)