# Firebase function (works in emulator), fails to execute a Google Cloud Workflow with: Error: 4 DEADLINE_EXCEEDED

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-firestore, google-cloud-functions

I have a Firebase function (in Typescript) that executes a Google Cloud Workflow.

- When I run the Cloud Workflow (using the Google Cloud Console) it runs as expected.
- When I run the Firebase functions in a ***local emulator***, it is able to execute the Cloud Workflow just fine, as expected.
- However, when I deploy the function, and it runs from Firebase (it is triggered by a Firestore update), it fails to create the Workflow execution:

```
Error: 4 DEADLINE_EXCEEDED: Deadline exceeded at callErrorFromStatus 
(/workspace/node_modules/@google-cloud/workflows/node_modules/@grpc/grpc-js/build/src/call.js:31:19) 
at Object.onReceiveStatus (/workspace/node_modules/@google-cloud/workflows/node_modules/@grpc/grpc-js/build/src/client.js:192:76)
at Object.onReceiveStatus (/workspace/node_modules/@google-cloud/workflows/node_modules/@grpc/grpc-js/build/src/client-interceptors.js:360:141)
at Object.onReceiveStatus (/workspace/node_modules/@google-cloud/workflows/node_modules/@grpc/grpc-js/build/src/client-interceptors.js:323:181)
at /workspace/node_modules/@google-cloud/workflows/node_modules/@grpc/grpc-js/build/src/resolving-call.js:94:78
at process.processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:77:11)
```

The relevant code is:

```js
import {ExecutionsClient} from "@google-cloud/workflows";

export const startWorkflow = functions
    .runWith({
      ingressSettings: "ALLOW_INTERNAL_ONLY",
      timeoutSeconds: 300,
    })
    .firestore.document(`items/{docId}`)
    .onCreate(async (request, context) => {
      Logger.info("Starting function in response to: request: " +
        `${JSON.stringify(request)} and context: ${JSON.stringify(context)}`);

      const itemId = request.id;
      Logger.info(`Need to start workflow for ItemId#${itemId}.`);
      const workflow = await new ItemProcessingService().startWorkflow(itemId);
      Logger.info(`Successfully started GCP Workflow: ${workflow}`);
    });

export class ItemProcessingService {
  async startWorkflow(itemId: string) {
    const client = new ExecutionsClient();
    const workflow = client.workflowPath("<my-project-id>", "us-central1", "item_processing_workflow");
    const params = {itemId: itemId};
    const request = {
      parent: workflow,
      execution: {argument: JSON.stringify(params)},
    };
    const callOptions = {
      timeout: 3000, // mills. See https://stackoverflow.com/q/61822332/117750
    };

    Logger.info(`Executing Google Cloud Workflow: ${workflow}: ` +
      `${JSON.stringify(params)} (options: ${JSON.stringify(callOptions)})`);

    const result = await client.createExecution(request, callOptions);

    Logger.info(`Response from GCP Cloud Workflows: ${JSON.stringify(result)}`);
    return result[0].name;
  }
}
```

- logs prior to the error show that the right workflow is being executed with the expected arguments.
- also, as mentioned, when I execute it from a local emulator, it executes the workflow as expected.

Comment: DEADLINE_EXCEEDED normally indicates a timeout.

Comment: I see. But how/why is it running from the emulator but not in the real function? I have also increased my function timeout as you can see in the runWith configuration.

Comment: The error message might not be coming from the function.

Comment: The stack trace shows that it’s from the call to the Google Cloud Workflow? And the logs prior to that line all show up, indicating that it was executed fine.

Comment: So I submitted a support ticket to Firebase (I am a Blaze plan user). And the next day the same code started working (I was experimenting with it, but nothing major changed except for a few logging statements). I am assuming that there was some account/service limits that I was subject to, that have since been lifted...